# Is there any way we can transfer data from python to front-end file in pyramid framework

Tags: pyramid

What I want to achieve is send some variables from back end to front end where I have a template files to create the front end. Is there any suggestions where I can find an answer for that.

Comment: [HTML Generation With Templating](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/templating.html)

Comment: See the documentation, including https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/templates.html and https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/templating.html

Comment: Thanks  @StevePiercy